# ldap_start_tls fails from Apache but works from PHP shell (phpsh)

Tags: php, apache, ldap

I have a LAMP application that uses LDAP binds (to Active Directory) to validate user credentials. This works on the production server running RHEL 6.2. I'm trying to set up my own test environment in a VM using CentOS 6.2 and similar versions of packages.

On my VM, calls to `ldap_start_tls` fail for the application when run inside Apache. I get:

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can't contact LDAP server in...
```

But on the same system, I installed [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org). If I use phpsh to execute the PHP code file, it works.

The code is a basic sequence of `ldap_connect`, `ldap_set_option` (to set LDAPv3), `ldap_start_tls`, and `ldap_bind`.

The LDAP server is using an internal Active Directory-generated certificate authority, so it isn't automatically trusted. In `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`, I have:

```
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

The setting seems to be working. If I change the value to `always`, `ldap_start_tls` fails in phpsh too. This is the same setting as in the production environment.

I tried installing what should be the AD root CA certificates by saving a .pem file (with 2 certificates) and adding this line to `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`:

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/certs/ad_roots.pem
```

I didn't see any change, but perhaps I needed to do more. And I'm not 100% sure those were the right certificates.

I think using phpsh is a valid test for the PHP setup, but it is running as a different user (root) so the environment is different. SELinux is on (`enforcing`), but I do not see any messages about access denials for Apache in `audit.log`.

Why doesn't this work for Apache?